# Which machine learning problem is this?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, nlp

I am not able to figure out what kind of machine learning is this:

Training set: consists of sentences with object labels for object phrases
Example:

```
"This is a black chair. It is next to a large bed."
```

Phrases `'This', 'black chair', 'it'` were annotated with the label `"chair"` and phrase `'large bed'` was annotated with the label `'bed'`. There are 18 available labels that can be assigned.

For an unannotated sentence, I want to predict the labels for each phrase in the sentence.

For example:

```
There is a study table in the corner of the room, behind it is a small chair.
```

I would like the model to predict a label (available 18 labels) for each phrase that represents an object in the above sentence.

Expected output:

```
'study table', 'it' -----> label 'table'

'small chair' -----------> label 'chair'
```

Is this a classification, regression, or a different kind of problem?

Answer (score 2):

Technically this is [sequence labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_labeling), the most common application being [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition).

However it looks like in this case you're trying to solve a problem of [coreference resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreference#Coreference_resolution), which is a quite difficult task in general. I think this usually involves a more complex model than simple sequence labeling, but I'm not an expert in this. You might want to search around this topic, there are certainly some relevant [papers](https://nlpprogress.com/english/coreference_resolution.html) and [tools](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/coref.shtml) about it.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your response as always. This is in fact a coreference resolution problem and would definitely require a different approach than simply using classification. I'll read more about it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to frame the problem.

One way is [multiclass classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification). The goal would be to assign a single discrete label to every phrase. In order to get phrases, you'll have to build a parse tree first. You did not list of all of the labels but let's assume they are all nouns. Then you'll need a Part-Of-Speech Tagger (POS Tagger) to find all noun phrases. Each noun phrase can be predicted to belong a class.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very interesting approach. So instead of output labels for each sentence, we would try to find a label for each phrase? And then we can combine these phrases and labels to obtain the original sentence? I do need the original sentence after labelling the phrases for the task to make sense because pronoun like "it" could refer to a different entity in different sentences.

Answer (score 1):

@Erwan probably gave you a better idea, but for a simpler problem, when each token has a separate class, this can be viewed as a Part of Speech Tagging, which is essentially a per-token multiclass problem. This assumes each token can be mapped only to one correct class. In such case the LSTM's output would be size, e.g. `(1, seq_length, hidden_dim)`, which you reshape to `(seq_length, hidden_dim)`, and `seq_length` becomes the batch dimension. You feed this output into a linear layers, to get a batch of outputs size `seq_length`. Now you can use NegativeLogLikelihood loss function for this batch. For each token you will have a one-hot vector (multiclass problem) of labels.